# Question understanding the projections $\pi_A, \pi_B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B$ be sets. Then there are natural projections $\pi_A, \pi_B$ defined by $\pi_A((a, b)) := a$ and $\pi_B((a, b)) := b$ for all $(a, b)$ in $A \times B$. Both these maps are surjective.

The definition of $\pi_A, \pi_B$ is confusing me. To my best recollection, you can't have two arrows emanating from the same element in the domain if you are working with functions. Please, elaborate on this.

Comment: Correct, but every element in the domain will be unique. That is, there is only one unique $(a_0, b_0)$ and that maps to $a_0$ (under $\pi_A$) it is surjective because $(a_0, b_1)$ maps to $a_0$ as well. I'm not certain if this clarifies anything, but I believe this is what your confusion was about.

Comment: Was that all that you had a question about? So the answer is that it was a typo?

Comment: @ MPW, the question still stands.

Comment: @ guest,  $\pi_A, \pi_B$ are two different functions as you said. Somehow that eluded me. This solves the problem :)

Comment: the "arrows" are a way of identifying ordered pairs in the function. Technically, you can have two arrows coming from one element of the domain. The restriction is that they must both point to the same element of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap up the question: $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are two different functions on $A\times B$.